# Security alternatives and how the icon reacts to that

Tags: swagger, openapi

[image]

[image]

**Code**

```
post:
  security: 
    - {}
    - MyUserToken: []
```

As far as I understand, these are two security options: either without authorisation, or using MyUserToken. That is there is logical Or between these two.

Could you tell me why when I have two security alternatives, the lock is locked.
And when there is only one security option, the lock is grey and unlocked. I would say, it should be vice versa.

Could you explain to me what is going on with this lock icon?